# django data history/auditing

Tags: django, audit, revision-history, django-reversion

I'm requiring model data history for my django project, and have come across the following products:

- django-reversion
- django-revisions
- django-simple-history
- django-audit-log
- cleanerversion

I can't find a recent recent comparison of these; a 2011 comparison (http://treyhunner.com/2011/09/django-and-model-history/) provided some pros and cons, but am wondering if anyone has anything more recent. Support for schema migrations (both south and 1.7 native) is necessary, seeing which user changed what would be nice, and support for foreignkeys and M2M would also be nice.

Answer (score 4):

The *model-audit* grid on Djangopackages gives a proper comparison of the various model history/auditing packages that are available.

See https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-audit/.